# iphone barcode reader database integration

Tags: barcode-scanner

I am trying to develop an iphone app which will scan a barcode and search it in the database and display the results. Actually i accomplished most part of it.
I can scan the barcode ( i am using zbar barcode reader ) and get the barcode number on the textfield but in order to search on my database i need to press a button i created.
What i need to do is after the barcode is scanned and the number is displayed on textfield get the search on the database immediately without need of pressing a button and display the results on other textfields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When zbar successfully recognizes a barcode, it triggers the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method in its delegate. You can place whatever further actions (such as sending the code to a web service, or hiding the view, etc.) within that method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it do the search after the scanner recieves a positive confirmation as a valid barcode. When the scan is accepted it will autosearch right from there.

Comment: thats possibble. but being completely newbie to iphone app programming can you point me where to start to do that ?